# nosetests in python how to specify the list of tests

Tags: python, nose

I'm wondering if there is a way I can specify the list of tests to run in a file.
I already know that you can do it in the command like so:

```
nosetests myfile.py:test1 myfile.py:test3 myfile.py:test20
```

but this will get out of hand easily.
I also know that there is a
loadTestsFromNames(names, module=None)
method as part of python unittest which can probably be used to load test names parsed from a yaml file but then if nose does not have such a thing implemented, it's quite useless to me.

Comment: You mean like to run all tests inside a directory?

Comment: No. In a single file (test suite), you have 10 test methods (test cases). In another file also you have some other test cases. You want to execute a mix of these tests in whatever order you want.

Comment: I believe that most programmers accept the notion that the order of execution for tests should not matter and should not be relied upon. That is, of course, an aside.

Comment: @jpmc26 I concur. If order matters you are coupling your tests to your logic and that's a big no-no. Else if you need certain data conditions or state before you can run the test, the unit tests aren't the right tool for those.

Comment: Firstly the reason behind my question is to run similar subsets of tests under different environments or software features and avoid code duplication. Secondly, regarding ordering of tests, my tests are functional and component tests, not unit-tests; hence order dependency is allowed but encouraged to be minimized. Ultimately I want to eliminate code duplication and reduce maintenance where certain tests  need to be run under various states and each state is tested in a test suite.

Comment: I would suggest that if the pieces actually depend on each other, then that should be a single test. A failure at one point should precipitate a failure of all of the tests that follow. A single error message indicating the initial failure is probably better than trying to figure out which error is the "real" one. Functional testing is a strange beast; I think some of the normal rules about short, isolated tests don't apply to it.

Answer (score 1):

Despite valid concerns in the comments to your question, it is perfectly valid to wish to run a select, limited number of testcases. For example: all testcases might be expensive, while a select set can indicate acceptance for more testing. Or you might need to control the "ordering" of tests - which is bad practice for unit tests (but with very slow integration tests, might be something you're forced to accept).

Two suggestions:

1) test tagging:
http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html

2) You can also write a small Nose plugin which selects tests based on patterns, or returns a fixed list of tests.

I use test tagging (nosetests -a "tagname") and it's flexible. The Nose plugin will work also; haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 0):

This one creates many xunit.xml-s which is something I wanted for jenkins.

```
list_of_tests = ["test_1", "test_2", "test_3"]
for atest in list_of_tests:
    test = Popen(['nosetests', '--nologcapture', 'myfile.py:%s'%atest, '-v', '-s', '--with-xunit', '--xunit-file=%s.xml' % atest], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
            for line in iter(test.stdout.readline, ''):
                print line.strip()
```